# svnadmin load checksum error

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, svnadmin

I have a SVN dump with some manually modified code in it, an I'm tryng to load the dump back into a repository. The problem is now I have checksum failures for the changed revisions. Is there any way to recalculate the md5 checksums for the entire dump file, or at least force svnadmin to load it?

Answer (score 1):

In some cases you don't need the md5 checksum. I was having this problem and simply removing those lines worked.

`sed -i '/Text-copy-source-md5/d' repo.dump`

Comment: Yup, it really worked for me - I had this problem after using https://github.com/jasperlee108/svndumpfilterIN/ - I just removed md5 hashes and everything worked properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

During the load the new checksum will be printed out (as far as i remember) as part of the error message...Just take the checksum and put into the field in the dump file instead.

Comment: I'm talking about a lot of files. Manually doing this would be very timeconsuming, especialy since I only get one md5 error at a time. Idealy I'd like to recalculate all of them or make svnadmin ignore hem completly

Comment: Hm..Ok...may be you can take a look here: http://svn.borg.ch/svndumptool/ and see if it's possible to use the code a way you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact problem and I fixed by removing the checksum lines entirely:

```
sed '/Text-content-md5/d' dumpfile.txt | svnadmin load repo --bypass-prop-validation
```